# Simplifying an XPath expression

Tags: xml, xpath

Is there a better way to test for non-existence of an attribute, or it's value being 0 or blank?

Currently I have to write

`//Comment[not(@ID) or @ID=0 or @ID='']`

But something simpler and less error prone if a condition is forgotten would be ideal.

EDIT: The following all also work

`//Comment[not(not(@ID * 1) = 0)]`

`//Comment[not(@ID * 1 > 0)]`

Comment: The two extra forms you put on the end are equivalent to what @Michael suggested, `[not(number(@ID))]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Is there a better way ..."

Nope.

Comment: Well that kinda sucks.  JavaScripts "falsy" has spoiled me.

Comment: I know what you mean, C# and .Net have spoiled me for C++ and MFC!

Comment: Ha, yeah, unfortunately, we're usually still stuck with good old SQL at the bottom of whatever stack we choose.

Comment: "Nope" may be correct, but without any explanation to back it up, we haven't much way of knowing whether it's correct or not. In fact the OP found some shorter ways (possibly "better").

Comment: LarsH, actually, it's logically impossible to prove something doesn't exist.  So it's impossible to write a good explanation to backup that there isn't a better way.

Comment: @Chad: People prove that lots of things don't exist, e.g. even numbers between 0.5 and 1, or solutions to Fermat's last theorem with n > 2, or a pure regular expression that can match unlimited pairs of parentheses. But even if P can't be proven, doesn't mean that good reasons can't be given for believing it. I couldn't logically prove to my wife that she should marry me, but I did manage to persuade her. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
test="(number(@ID))"
```

might do what you want. It will return false when the attribute is absent, blank, or "0", but it will also return false for some other cases, for example `ID="not-a-number"`. You need to specify your requirements more precisely, for example how do you want to treat ID="00" or ID=" 0 " (with spaces).

Comment: I just tried using `//Comment[(number(@ID))]` and it didn't select anything.  No nodes with or without an ID, regardless of the value

Comment: @Chad, that matches what Michael said. Assuming you have no elements with ID="2".

Comment: @Chad, note that you need to flip the sense of the test for your purpose: `//Comment[not(number(@ID))]`

Comment: @Chad: ok, you're right... It took me a while to see why this happens. Remember that a predicate containing a number, e.g. `[n]`, is interpreted to mean `[position() = n]`, not `[boolean(n)]`. So `//Comment[(number(@ID))]` will only select Comment elements that are the IDth child of their parents. Try `//Comment[not(number(@ID))]` and you'll get what Michael intended. Or try `//Comment[boolean(number(@ID))]` to select Comments with ID="2", etc.